# Li item on two lines. Second line has no margin

Tags: html, css, html-lists, font-awesome

I'm currently working on an unordered list containing list items with taglines. I'm having a problem concerning one list item, which is long enough to take up two lines (See image)

[image]

I want it so that the second line is aligned with the first line. This is the HTML code i'm using. I used fontAwesome for the check images.

```css
ul {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="fa-ul custom-list">
  <li><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>List item on 1 line</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>List item on 1 line</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>This is a list item that actually takes up 2 lines. Looks ugly</li>
</ul>
```

I already tried to enter multiple `&nbsp;` in between '2' and 'lines' but that seems like a really bad practice to me. I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: I've moved your code into a Stack Snippet to make it easier for everyone to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is because the tick is inline content so when the text wraps it will continue to flow as usual.

You can stop this behaviour by taking advantage of `text-indent`:

> The text-indent property specifies how much horizontal space should be left before the beginning of the first line of the text content of an element.

*text-indent (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent)*

By supplying a negative `text-indent` you can tell the first line to shift a desired amount to the left. If you then specify a positive `padding-left` you can cancel this offset out.

In the following example a value of `1.28571429em` is used because it is the `width` set on the `.fa-fw` by font-awesome.

```css
ul {
  width: 300px;
}
li {
    padding-left: 1.28571429em;
    text-indent: -1.28571429em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="fa-ul custom-list">
    <li><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>List item on 1 line</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>List item on 1 line</li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>This is a list item that actually takes up 2 lines. Looks ugly</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 9):

you can just add this to your ul:

```
ul {
text-indent:-20px; 
margin-left:20px;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/JfGVE/709/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still gonna have to give #Hobbes the correct answer because of actual explanation

Answer (score 3):

You could remove the check out of the page flow by setting them with `position:absolute`

```css
ul {
  width: 300px;
}
.fa-fw {
  position: absolute;
  left: -22px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="fa-ul custom-list">
  <li><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>List item on 1 line</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>List item on 1 line</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw"></i>This is a list item that actually takes up 2 lines. Looks ugly</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use "display:table" as style for li, and inside create a span with "display:table-cell" styling. Or create corresponding class. Like this:

```
<li style="display:table"><span style="display:table-cell">text with 
all lines indented</span></li>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can put your text in a `div` and give `float:left` to your inner `li` and  `div`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ul li{
padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;
text-indent: -1em;
}
```

add padding and text indent - that moves the text from the li:before.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list-style-position:outside.  Do your CSS like this:

```
ul li {
   list-style-position:outside;
     ... whatever else ...
}
```

or directly inline:

```
<li style = 'list-style-position:outside'>stuff </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    
    ul li {
    display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
    }
    
     ul li:before {
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    content: "\f054";
    margin-right: 7px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin-top: 2px;
    }
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<ul><li>Visit the Museum of Modern Art in Manhattan</li>
    <li>Visit to Bali with tripraja</li>
    <li>Check out Campbell's Soup Cans by Warhol and The Dance (I) by Matisse</li>
    <li>Behold masterpieces by Gauguin, Dali, Picasso, and Pollock</li>
    <li>Enjoy free audio guides available in English, French, German, Italian, Spanish, Portuguese.</li></ul>
```