# How to use css before attribute as own colum like a li in a ul

Tags: css, flexbox

Hello i searched since  hours i don't know i maybe missing something but i can't wrapp my head around that i need 2 colums one is generated via inserted content by css and the other should be the normal content text but i simply don't get it.

i want to create a custom list so i need exactly the Behavior of a

```html
<ul><li></li></ul>
```

```html
    <div class="flex-container">
    Long Text is Here Long Text is Here Long Text is Here Long Text is 
Here Long Text is Here Long Text is Here Long Text is Here Long Text is 
Here Long Text is Here Long Text is Here This long Text Schould be 
<strong class="no-wrap">Importent: </strong> 
<strong class="no-wrap"> All in One single line &nbsp; </strong> 
i only need one colum for the before tag it should not wrap the text nodes 
before and after the strong nodes i need a 2 colum layout one col for the 
before css attr and one col for the rest of the text ignoring the strong

    </div>
```

```css
@import "compass/css3";
.flex-container:before { 
counter-increment: h22; 
content: counter(h22) ". "; 
min-width: 0.8cm;    
}

.flex-container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.no-wrap{
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

it should look like this:

- Long Text is Here Long Text is Here Long Text is Here Long Text is 
  Here Long Text is Here Long Text is Here Long Text is Here Long Text is 
  Here Long Text is Here Long Text is Here This long Text Schould be 
  **Importent: All in One single line**   
  i only need one colum for the before tag it should not wrap the text nodes 
  before and after the strong nodes i need a 2 colum layout one col for the 
  before css attr and one col for the rest of the text ignoring the strong

https://codepen.io/frank-dspeed/pen/KJMRwG

Comment: never ever make a text container a flexbox container, this is the first rule ... wrap everything inside a div

Comment: Thanks for the rule set my frind but i have legacy data that i can't migrate in time so i am not able to change that at present

Comment: then don't use flexbox, and rely on something else .. make the pseudo element position:absolute then add some padding to the content

Comment: Thanks again Temani Alifi am working on such a solution but i am not a good designer

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/33362748/8620333 .. and their related links you will get some worarounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i don't got valuable answers in time i will now answer it my self i found the solution with some experiments took me only some hours because i am not familar with such situations.

```css
body { counter-reset: h21 h22 h23; }
.flex-container:before { 
    counter-increment: h22; 
    content: counter(h22) ". "; 
    min-width: 0.8cm;
    margin-left: -0.8cm;
    position: absolute;
  }
.flex-container { 
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0.8cm;
    font-size: 11pt; 
    font-weight: normal; 
    margin: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 11pt;     
  /*disabled by me because if we choose flex this can't render right as it treats tags as cols*/
}
```

https://codepen.io/frank-dspeed/pen/xMOagZ