# Align icon on right for multiline text with list item

Tags: css, flexbox

To start with, here is the code:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  max-inline-size: 10rem;
}

ul li .fa:first-of-type {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

ul li .fa:last-of-type {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul>
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i> Short text
    <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i> Long text wrapping on multiple lines
    <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The problem I have is that the icon on the right of the multiline text gets pushed to the edge of the list item, while it looks OK when the text is on single line.

I am using flex as I want the text to align vertically on the left edge and that needs to stay unchanged.

Comment: if you remove display:flex you have what you want concerning the right icon (forget the left one)

Comment: yeah, I get that :) is there a way to align text vertically without using flex and ideally keeping the icons aligned to the top of the text horizontally?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33363184/8620333

Comment: pretty close to what I need, just need to figure out how to keep the icon on right on the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a width for the list item, but in order to align the icons to the right side you should use `margin-left: auto;` on the `ul li .fa:last-of-type`

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  max-inline-size: 10rem;
  position:relative;
  padding-left: 30px;
  
}
span.text{
  display: inline-block;
  /*width:80px;*/
}

ul li .fa:first-of-type {
  margin-right: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

ul li .fa:last-of-type {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul>
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="text">Short text</span>
    <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="text"> Long text wrapping on multiple lines </span>
    <i class="fa fa-address-book" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For more on working with flex, you should check this article https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I don't want icons on the right side to be pushed to the edge.

Comment: You don't want them to be pushed to the edge, yes, but if you want to align each icon on the right side to be in line with the first row and aligned with every other above and below, you should set a width tothe text. I've updated the snippet , wrapped the text in spans, set the width of it , so now the icons are aligned to right, beside the text. Is that you're lookin for? You can make the width bigger to give more space for the text

Comment: I don't need to icons on the right hand side to be aligned vertically (only horizontally), just want the icon to sit immediatelly after text. I think I will have to drop this idea and stick to aligning icons to the right edge (the way you have done).

Comment: check my snippet now. There is a way if you make the first icon absolute, and set padding  to the list-item